# Proper Setup of Tab Indents

Tags: emacs

Using Emacs with C source code, I want pressing the tab key to insert a tab character, and have it show a tab as being 2 spaces wide. So this is what I put in my ~/.emacs:

`(setq c-default-style "linux")

(setq-default c-basic-offset 2

tab-width 2)`

However it does not count a tab as one column, but 2 in this case, and it causes a problem when I want to, for instance, jump to the spot that gcc specifies in an error message.

```
int main()  
{  
    if(1)  
    {  
        if(2)  
        {  
            error  
        }  
    }  
}
```

With this error:

```
test.c:7:5 error: `error` undeclared (first use in this function)
```

So when I select the error it jumps to the wrong spot. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Never** have the ASCII HORIZONTAL TAB (HT) **character** (byte value 0x9) represent anything but "move to next 8-column boundary".  Messing with this default messes up all sorts of unix programs, and generally causes problems.

If you want 2-space **indentation** that's fine, and it's also fine that you want it to happen when you hit the TAB **key**.  Emacs separates the notion of the HT character from that of indentation, and each can be controlled separately.

Start with just

```
(setq c-basic-offset 2)
```

in your `.emacs` file.  Now, whenever you hit the TAB key in a C program, emacs will automatically re-ident that line appropriately.  You can use `M-i` or `C-q TAB` to insert a real HT character.

There's lots more customization you can do if this still isn't quite what you want, but this is the right way to begin.

Comment: Is it not advantageous to have the HT character be of variable size, so that one person who wants 4 space tabs can have it his way, and the same source code can be viewed with 2 space tabs for another person who prefers it that way? This concept doesn't mess with any unix programs I know. Anyway, it seems that even with inserting a real HT character, Emacs still treats it as 8 characters in terms of column number, rather than one character, so my problem has made no progress.

Comment: @kaykun: It's not so much that programs get confused by HT characters, as that a lot of (mostly older) utilities know that a HT corresponds to 8 spaces, and although you can override this individually, it turns out to be a bit of a drag.  Even as far as simply viewing a file goes, code written for, eg, 4-space TABS might look alright at 2-space TABs, but the other way around will almost always come out looking bad.

Comment: @kaykun: Can you please clarify your final sentence?  If you've set `c-basic-offset` to 2 and leave `tab-width` at 8, can you describe what happens when you hit the TAB key at the beginning of the third line of your input?

Comment: If code written for 2-space tabs looks that bad with 4-space tabs it's as easy as changing it back to 2-spaces. That's the flexibility provided by using HT characters; with spaces a person is forced to stick with one tab width that he or she may not like.

Comment: Setting only c-basic-offset to 2 indents to two spaces, but that isn't my problem. The only thing I want is for one tab to be considered as one column number, for the reason that gcc treats HT characters as one column number and it affects its error message.

Comment: Try setting `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil`.  This should force any indentation that emacs inserts to be only spaces, avoiding the column-counting problems.

Comment: That would be a solution, if it hasn't already been pointed out that I want tab characters for indentation in my code, not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `c-syntactic-indentation` to nil?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoking gcc with `-ftabstop=2`?